# Visual Studio 2017 and Resharper test runner

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, visual-studio-2017

Resharper 2016.3 cannot see xUnit-based unit tests in my ASP.Net Core project in VS2017.

If I "Run All Test" from the [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) menu, it finds no tests. Also there's no "circle" icon next to `[Fact]` attributes. But the built-in VS test runner finds and executes all tests successfully. Am I missing something, or Resharper unit test support does not work in VS2017 yet?

Comment: Use its EAP release.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I am already using the latest EAP (2017.1 EAP 7). Visual Studio's own test runner and `dotnet test` both work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update to ReSharper 2017.1 (currently in [Early Access Preview](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/)). Microsoft rewrote the `dotnet test` which broke the existing implementation.

Comment: The latest EAP, which I just installed as of this comment (2017.1 EAP 7) does not discover any tests in my UnitTests assembly. I am using xunit with the proper NuGet packages referenced by the UnitTests assembly. Visual Studio's own test runner works perfectly, as does `dotnet test`.

Comment: Looks like there may be a bug in the latest EAP that means tests sometimes aren't being found in the editor. They should be listed in the Unit Test Explorer once you build the project, but nothing in the editor. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464077